# Italian words with post-stress -/tj/-

Tags: consonants, phonotactics, italian

It is well known that Italian -/.tj/- developed into -/t.tsj/- after stressed syllables (gratiam -> grazia). There are, however, several rare words that end in post-stressed -/tj/- like "òstia", "àstio", "modèstia", "lìtio" and so on. However, I have noticed that all of these feature an *s* in the coda of the preceding syllable, leaving me to think they were spared from the sound shift that turned -*ti*- to -*zi*-  because of the phonotactical impossibility (in early Romance,  I suppose) of the -/s.ts/- cluster, at least in that position. What I find puzzling is how, despite all this, there is a single exception in the word *sàrtia* (which by the way refers to a steel cable used to keep a mast stationary), which despite not having the *s* there sounds perfectly "right" to my (North) Italian ears.

What gives? Shouldn't it sound weird or wrong?

Comment: Interesting question. Wiktionary says it’s a loan from Byzantine Greek (ἐξάρτια), which could be an explanation. Romance palatalisations are a minefield, but I **think** Spanish _jarcia_ and Catalan _xarxa_ /'ʃaɾʃə/ (instead of _*jarza_ and _*xarça_) also indicate that this is not an inherited word that developed all the way from Latin, but one that was borrowed later on and only took part in _some_ of the subsequent sound changes, evidently postdating the /tj/ > /tsj/ one. (I believe _grazia_ is also an early reborrowing from Latin – otherwise, it ought to have become _*grazza_.)

Comment: (Of course _litio_, which you cite as well, is another example of a word with an unexpected /tj/ cluster, but in this case it’s known for certain that the word is a recent borrowing: the name itself was only coined as a Latinate neologism by Swedish chemist Jöns Jakob Berzelius around 1817. _Sartia_ appears to be a good deal older than that, at least.)

Answer (score 1):

The regular outcome of *-sti-* + vowel in Italian words inherited from Latin is [ʃ(ː)], as in *uscio* from Latin *ōstium.*

The use of *-sti-* [stj] + vowel is part of the Italian academic pronunciation of Latin (I described the rule in more detail here: [How to pronounce the sequence "ti" when reading Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10684/9)). So we can infer that words like "ostia" and "modestia" didn't develop regularly as inherited words, but rather are learned forms. When not after S, Latin *-ti-* before a vowel is generally pronounced by Italians as [t͡s(ː)j] or [t͡s(ː)i] and respelled in Italian learned forms as *-zi-*, but there seems to be an exception for cases where the Latin spelling has *th*. Thus *litio,* *simpatia,* etc. In inherited words,  *-ti-* did not become [t͡s(ː)j]: it could variously end up as [t͡s(ː)], [d͡ʒ], or [t͡ʃ(ː)].

None of the rules for the alteration of *-ti-* to something else are synchronic constraints in Italian phonology (or at least, they aren't inviolable constraints): /tj/ exists unchanged in forms like *partiamo.* In that sense, I don't think it's too surprising from a synchronic perspective that /ˈsartja/ is inoffensive to your ears. But I don't know the diachronic explanation of how *sartia* developed its current pronunciation.

Comment: Thanks for the [ʃ(ː)] thing, I had no idea. I had noticed a great deal of words like "simpatia" and "partiamo", but didn't include them because I felt that the stressed /i/ (not even a /j/!) in the first, and the stressed /a/ in the second somewhat relax phonotactical constraints: in the sense that Italian speakers might be more willing to perform unusual phonetics in a stressed syllable than in an unstressed one. Cheers!